# insert new item in a sorted list of divs

Tags: javascript, alphabetical

```
<list>
    <div>abacus</div>
    <div>abstract paint</div>
    <div>australian coco</div>
     .........
     .........
     .........
    <div>mango</div>
    <div>parrot</div>
    <div>salt</div>
    <div>upi</div>
</list>
```

The "list" tag is inside the `body` of a HTML document... "list" tag contains over 5000 divs... as it is a very big number, I present a part of it...

I need to insert a new div (like `<div>apache</div>`) among these divs alphabetically according to these divs  `innerHTML` (`innerHTML` contains only alphabets and numbers, no sign)... but the problem is if I use `insertBefore()` method, I will get the div at the end of the list... How can I do that...??

please don't use any jQuery... only Javascript...

Comment: You're not really reordering divs, but inserting a new item into an already sorted list, right?

Comment: yes... @Ates Goral... you are right... but I want the list even sorted after I insert the new div...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 var list         = document.getElementsByTagName('list')[ 0 ],
     DOMitems     = list.getElementsByTagName('div'),
     items        = Array.prototype.slice.call( DOMitems );

function addItem( text ) {
    var position          = 0,
        newElem           = document.createElement('div');
        newElem.innerHTML = text;

    items.push( newElem );
    items.sort(function( a, b ) {
        return a.innerHTML.localeCompare( b.innerHTML );
    });

    position = items.indexOf( newElem );
    list.insertBefore( newElem, DOMitems[ position ] );
}

addItem('apache');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9UNB3/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Seems weird you are using divs and not an ul/li. This is one approach you can do.

```
var words = document.getElementById("wordsList")
var indexes = null;
function InsertItem​(word) {
    if (!indexes) {
        getItems();
    }        
    indexes.push(word);
    console.log(indexes);
    indexes.sort();
    var position = indexes.indexOf(word);
    var list = words.getElementsByTagName("div");    
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.innerHTML = word;
    words.insertBefore(newDiv, list[position]);
}
function getItems(){
    var elems = words.getElementsByTagName("div");
    indexes = [];
    for (var i=0;i<elems.length;i++) {
        indexes.push(elems[i].innerHTML);
    }
}

InsertItem("apple");
InsertItem("aaaaa");
InsertItem("zzzzz");
​
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VV2mL/)

Comment: You can change it to meet your needs, there is one with my example, look at the fiddle. I am sure you are smart enough to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to know before what div-nr you want to insert,
you might use: insertBefore(node,yourlist.childNodes[(nr-1)*2])

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset=UTF-8>
<title>Insert</title>

<list id=alist>
<div>abacus</div>
<div>abstract paint</div>
<div>australian coco</div>
<div>mango</div>
<div>parrot</div>
<div>salt</div>
<div>upi</div>
</list>

<script>
var nr = 3,//insert before the third div
alist = document.getElementById('alist'),
node = document.createElement('div');
node.innerHTML = 'apache';

alist.insertBefore(node,alist.childNodes[(nr-1)*2]);
</script>
```